# sql query to get desired output

Tags: sql-server

I have Two columns in my table `"Edition"`

Now when I pass two dates, then the output should be all the rows but for all the rows in between should add `"New"` as a Result.

So, My table contains:

```
id          edition_date            
----------- ----------------------- 
242         2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 
243         2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 
244         2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 
245         2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

When I pass `2012-02-01` and `2012-03-31`

**Desired OUTPUT:**

```
id          edition_date            Result   
----------- ----------------------- ----------- 
242         2011-01-01 00:00:00.000 
243         2011-02-01 00:00:00.000 New
244         2011-03-01 00:00:00.000 New
245         2011-04-01 00:00:00.000
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @start datetime, @end datetime
select @start = convert(datetime, '2011-02-01',120),
       @end = convert(datetime, '2011-03-01',120)

select *,
    case when edition_date between @start and @end then 'New' end as Result
from
    Edition
```