# Recursively updating statement in sql server

Tags: sql-server, recursion

I have a table with IDs varchar(10). Possible values are like

```
create table temp(id varchar(10))
insert into id('01')
insert into id('011')
insert into id('0110')
insert into id('01110')
insert into id('011111')
insert into id('02')
insert into id('020')
insert into id('0222')
```

and so on .i.e lengths of 2 to 6. Our new requirement says that we have to have decimal after 2 numbers i.e
01 remains same; 011 becomes 011.1; 0110 to 01.10; 01110 to 01.11.0 ;011111 to 01.11.11
I manually wrote update statements but there are 700 such distinct IDs
How can I recursively apply a update statement.

Thanks

Comment: any chance you can edit your question and layout your current values and desired output in a more clear manner. it's impossible to read the question in this format.

Comment: take a look at this question to see how you can improve the readability of your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801247/sql-query-to-get-desired-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick set-based (non-looping) approach would use a `Case` statement like this:

```
Update dbo.Temp
Set id = 
  Case 
  When Len(Id) <= 2 Then Id
  When Len(Id) Between 3 and 4 Then Left(Id, 2)
       + '.' + Substring(Id, 3, 2)
  When Len(Id) Between 5 and 6 Then Left(Id, 2) 
       + '.' + Substring(Id, 3, 2) 
       + '.' + Substring(Id, 6, 2)
  End;
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e733/1).

Answer (score 0):

Your question's not too clear, but if I understand correctly, sounds like you want to insert a decimal point after every second number.  One way is with a loop:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(id VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #t (id) VALUES ('01'),('011'),('0110'),('01110'),('011111'),('02'),('020'),('0222'),('010203040');

DECLARE @iteration INT = 0, @rowsAffected INT = 1;

WHILE @rowsAffected > 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE  #t
    SET     id = STUFF(id, 3 + (@iteration * 3), 0, '.')
    WHERE   LEN(id) > 2 + (3 * @iteration) ;

    SELECT  @rowsAffected = @@ROWCOUNT
            , @iteration += 1;
END;
```

You need to be careful that by adding extra characters into your data, you don't overflow the size of the column.